# How to swap Ctrl and Meta (Alt) keys under FreeDOS OS

Tags: keyboard, dos

I'm looking for a solution to swap the Ctrl and Alt keys under FreeDOS OS. Does anybody know anything about this? Maybe there is a program similar to 'loadmap' that is used in GNU OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried that, but the command to use to make your own keyboard mappings file is [KC](http://help.fdos.org/en/hhstndrd/base/keyb-kc.htm) and the command to load a keyboard mapping (typically called from AUTOEXEC.BAT) is [KEYB](http://help.fdos.org/en/hhstndrd/base/keyb.htm).

If it is only for a limited number of shortcuts you want to modify you can also have a look at XKEYB and KEYMAN that together will allow you to make your own keyboard macros that can include the use of CTRL and ALT keys.